# jQuery function to work on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#time-options').on('change', function() {
        if ($('#time-options').prop('checked')) {
            $('#time-options-div').slideDown(500);
            return false;
        } else {
            $('#time-options-div').slideUp(500);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

So whenever the `#time-options` is checked, the div slides down. But sometimes the `#time-options` is already selected when the page loads, so in this case I would like the `#time-options-div` to be already open.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to invoke the `change` event manually once, after the event got bound.

```
$('#time-options').on('change', function(){
  if($('#time-options').prop('checked')){
    $('#time-options-div').slideDown(500);
    return false;
  }else{
    $('#time-options-div').slideUp(500);
    return false;
  }
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to also run the block inside the on change function. With some refactoring you can also have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   function slide(){
     if($('#time-options').prop('checked')){
        $('#time-options-div').slideDown(500);
        return false;
     }else{
        $('#time-options-div').slideUp(500);
        return false;
    }    
}

$('#time-options').on('change',slide);    

slide();
});
```